# Корректная запись данных в *.mp3 файл

Tags: кодировка, java, mp3

Проблема в том, что при скачивании нормального файла, вместо ожидаемой музыки, сохраняется glitch'енутая версия: с посторонними свистами и внезапными изменениями темпа песни.

Скачанный файл отличается от оригинального хаотичным вкраплением знаков '?'. В остальном же, они идентичны. Казалось бы, очевидных проблем с кодировкой нет.

Методы. Сохранение в файл:

```
public static void Save(String content, String filePath, String charset)
{
    try
    {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        charset = charset != null ? charset : Charset.defaultCharset().name(); //здесь windows-1251
        Writer bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(file), charset));
        bw.append(content);
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

Скачивание:

```
public String getString(String urlAdress, String charset)
{
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlAdress);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        charset = charset != null ? charset : Charset.defaultCharset().name(); //здесь windows-1251
        InputStream is = (InputStream) connection.getContent();
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, charset));
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        char[] bufferChars = new char[1024];
        int bufferSize;
        while ((bufferSize = reader.read(bufferChars)) != -1)
        {
            content.append(bufferChars, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @Анна Киселёва, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бинарные данные (т.е. mp3-файл) следует читать и записывать в бинарном виде, а не текстовом, как сделано у вас.